# How to fix "TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()" on the line "if form.validate_on_submit():"?

Tags: python, wtforms

Environment:

Python 3.7

I have a flask web form that fills a Mysql table.

I get this error :

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

on the line:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
```

of my routes.py

I checked the model and the class form, but I don't see any issue. I am not using "len" function on any integer in my code.

I saw a few similar questions here in Stackoverflow, but the solution is not appropriate for my fields.

I suspect the boolean fields enable, smartphone_allowed, and computer_allowed to be the source of this issue. But I have no idea how to fix that. The error message is not clear. It speaks about "len", and I don't use len at all!

**models.py:**

```
class Task(db_mysql.Model):
    __tablename__ = "W551je5v_pb_tasks"
    id = db_mysql.Column('id', db_mysql.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db_mysql.Column('name', db_mysql.Unicode)
    introduction = db_mysql.Column('introduction', db_mysql.Unicode)
    description = db_mysql.Column('description', db_mysql.Unicode)
    id_platform = db_mysql.Column('id_platform', db_mysql.Integer, db_mysql.ForeignKey('W551je5v_pb_platforms.id'))
    id_type_task = db_mysql.Column('id_type_task', db_mysql.Integer, db_mysql.ForeignKey('W551je5v_pb_type_tasks.id'))
    url_keywords = db_mysql.Column('url_keywords', db_mysql.Integer)
    url_keywords_description = db_mysql.Column('url_keywords_description', db_mysql.Unicode)
    minimum = db_mysql.Column('minimum', db_mysql.Integer)
    minimum_description = db_mysql.Column('minimum_description', db_mysql.Unicode)
    url_list = db_mysql.Column('url_list', db_mysql.Integer)
    url_list_description = db_mysql.Column('url_list_description', db_mysql.Unicode)
    url_usernames = db_mysql.Column('url_usernames', db_mysql.Integer)
    url_usernames_description = db_mysql.Column('url_usernames_description', db_mysql.Unicode)
    platform = db_mysql.relationship(Platform, backref="W551je5v_pb_tasks")

    daily_limit = db_mysql.Column('daily_limit', db_mysql.Integer)
    hourly_limit = db_mysql.Column('hourly_limit', db_mysql.Integer)
    enable = db_mysql.Column ('enable', db_mysql.Integer)
    smartphone_allowed =db_mysql.Column ('smartphone_allowed', db_mysql.Integer)
    computer_allowed = db_mysql.Column ('computer_allowed', db_mysql.Integer)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Task('{self.id}','{self.name}','{self.introduction}','{self.description}',  \
        '{self.id_platform}','{self.id_type_task}','{self.daily_limit}','{self.hourly_limit}','{self.enable}','{self.smartphone_allowed}','{self.computer_allowed}')"
```

forms.py:

```
class NewTaskForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=200)])
    introduction = TextAreaField('Introduction', render_kw={'rows': 5},
                                 validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=12000)])
    description = TextAreaField('Description', render_kw={'rows': 20},
                                 validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=12000)])
    platform = SelectField('Platform', validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[],coerce=int)
    type_task = QuerySelectField('Type Task', validators=[DataRequired()], query_factory=GetTypesTask,
                                     get_label='name')
    url_keywords = BooleanField('Url Keywords', default=False)
    url_keywords_description = TextAreaField('Url Keywords description', render_kw={'rows': 10})
    minimum = BooleanField('Minimum', default=False)
    minimum_description = TextAreaField('Minimum description', render_kw={'rows': 10})
    url_list = BooleanField('Url List', default=False)
    url_list_description = TextAreaField('Url list description', render_kw={'rows': 10})
    url_usernames = BooleanField('Url Usernames', default=False)
    url_usernames_description = TextAreaField('Url Names description', render_kw={'rows': 10})
    daily_limit = StringField('Daily Limit', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=1, max=4)])
    hourly_limit = StringField('Hourly Limit', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=1, max=4)])
    enable = BooleanField('Enable', default=False)
    smartphone_allowed = BooleanField('Smartphone allowed', default=False)
    computer_allowed = BooleanField('Computer allowed', default=False)
    
    submit = SubmitField('Save')
```

**routes.py:**

```
@app.route('/task/<int:task_id>/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_task(task_id):


    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        task = Task.query.get_or_404(task_id)
        form = NewTaskForm(obj=task)
        prepare_content_SelectList = db_mysql.session.query(Platform.id, Platform.name, Category.name) \
            .order_by(Platform.name).join(Category).all()
        list_content_SelectList = []
        for content in prepare_content_SelectList:
            label = str(content[1] + ' - ' + content[2])
            string_id= str(content[0])
            list_content_SelectList.append((string_id, label))
        #print(f"list_content_SelectList : {list_content_SelectList}")


        form.platform.choices = list_content_SelectList
        print(f"form.errors : {form.errors}")
        if form.is_submitted ():
            print("submitted")



        if form.validate_on_submit():
```

**my table W551je5v_pb_tasks :**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. I get it. It was my integer fields that had some validators with Lenght. I simply removed these parameters. Now my daily_limit and hourly_limit  fields are like these:

```
daily_limit = StringField('Daily Limit')
hourly_limit = StringField('Hourly Limit')
```

instead of :

```
daily_limit = StringField('Daily Limit', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=1, max=4)])
hourly_limit = StringField('Hourly Limit', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=1, max=4)])
```

Comment: Any reason you are not using `IntegerField`  for the integer columns?